# create html input for mathematical expression

Tags: html, css, html-input

I need to know how can i create an input text in HTML for a mathematical formula like the one in geogebra.org/classic

[image: Img1]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please feel free to come back and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

To create an HTML input for mathematical expression, you can use a third-party library such as MathQuill or MathJax.

Download the MathQuill library and add it to your project.
Create an HTML input element and add a class of mathquill-embedded-latex to it:

```js
var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
var mathField = MQ.MathField(document.getElementById('math-input'), {
  handlers: {
    edit: function() {
      console.log(mathField.latex()); // log the LaTeX string to the console
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="mathquill-embedded-latex" id="math-input" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.js" integrity="sha512-7jEhcM7FbjGHo1ejs1iw1J8FxcnACx7Z3lG29gQ5vTBe2U/gaQpzwjzPCyg32zTwXCloQDdorpLufmu0nBIqnQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

22:-)